# Differentiability at the limit of non-differentiable points

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, continuity

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Suppose there exists a sequence $(x_n)_{n \ge 1} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that:

1. there exists $x_\infty \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x_n \to x_\infty$ as $n \to \infty$
2. $f$ is not differentiable at each point $x_n$

Do we know that $f$ cannot then be differentiable at $x_\infty$? I suspect it is impossible for $f$ to be differentiable at $x_\infty$ but I have not been able to prove this myself. I have tried approximating the Newton quotients at $x_\infty$ by those at $x_n$, making use of continuity, but to no avail. I have also not found this result anywhere online.

Hints towards the proof of this result or counter-examples would be greatly appreciated.

---

Of course, after posting, I realized that this question may be stated more succinctly. For $f \in C(\mathbb{R})$, is the set $$A := \{x \in \mathbb{R}\ |\ f'(x) \text{ does not exist}\}$$ closed?

Comment: I believe that $x^2\arccos(\cos(\frac{\pi}{x}))$ (with value $0$ at $x=0$) is a counterexample using the sequence $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$. However I would recommend you check it as I haven't been too thorough.

Comment: For continuous functions it is even possible for the set $A$ to be both dense (in the reals) and have a dense complement -- see [Construct a function on a bounded interval on $\Bbb{R}$ which is continuous everywhere but differentiable only at irrationals.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2784334/13130)

Comment: @Fishbane thank you for this example. It is quite interesting, the function you gave is squeezed between $y = pi x^2$ and $y = 0$ at the point $x=0$ so I believe it is differentiable there.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro thank you for this comment. I was unaware of just how "badly" behaved the set of differentiable points of a continuous function may be. Very interesting

Comment: Of related interest is [*Two functions whose powers make fractals*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2589243) by Marc Frantz (1998). The functions there are not everywhere continuous, but they nonetheless might be interesting. For more about these types of functions, see [this 13 December 2006 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/m9SfPUdr4I4/m/kcpzwLqqtJUJ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $g$ be a continuous no-where differentiable function on $[0,1]$ and $f(x)=x[g(x)-g(0)]$. Then $f$ is not differentiable at each of the points $x_n=\frac 1 n$ but it is differentiable at $0$ with $f'(0)=0$.

Comment: This is a wonderfully simple example, thank you