# What is the relation between a smooth path and a Holder Continuous Path

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity

I have recently been studying $\alpha$-Holder continuous paths for $\alpha \in (0,1]$, where when we $\alpha = 1$, we have Lipschitz continuity.

My definition of a smooth path is one that has infinitely many continuous derivatives.

My question is: can a path that is $\alpha$-Holder continuous for any $\alpha \in (0,1]$ be smooth? Intuitively I thought the answer was no. My thought process was that the sample paths of Brownian motion have $\alpha$ holder continuity for $\alpha = 1/2$. However, these are also famously non-differentiable - and i guess that this holds for $\alpha < \frac{1}{2}$.

I also know that not all smooth functions are Lipschitz continuous. So is there a relation in general between $\alpha$ and smoothness?

Thanks

Comment: On [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition) it lists continuously differentiable functions as subset of $\alpha$-holder continuous functions. Clearly, smooth functions are subsets of continuously differentiable functions.
Caveat here is that these conditions only hold for compact (i.e. closed & bounded) domain. But per definition a path has a closed interval as domain right?

Comment: @student91 So then it would be possible to have a continuously differentiable function that is holder continuous with $\alpha <1/2$? Yes a path has a closed interval as domain, usually $[0,T]$.

Comment: Yes, the constant function $f(x)=0$ is the most boring example and there's also more interesting examples.

Comment: @student91 sorry by $\alpha < 1/2$ I mean a function that is not holder continuous for $\alpha \geq 1/2$, since obviously if a function is alpha holder continuous for $\alpha = a$, then it is alpha holder continuous for all $\alpha \leq a$.

Comment: Then the answer by Nick should address that question. If it does, don't forget to accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, no. If a path is Lipschitz, the in fact it is $\alpha-$Hölder continuous for all $\alpha\in(0,1)$. But Lipschitz paths are not guaranteed to be smooth, just consider as a simple example the graph of $f(x)=|x|$ around the origin.

Comment: Thank you, so there appears to be no real relation between $\alpha$ - holder continuity and smoothness? A function that is Lipschitz may or may not be smooth while a function that is $\alpha$-holder continuous ONLY for $\alpha <= a$ may or may not be smooth.

Comment: @Jamal: In fact, a Lipschitz function $f:{\mathbb R} \rightarrow {\mathbb R}$ -- even if it is also **strictly increasing** -- can fail to be differentiable at every point of a set that is dense in ${\mathbb R}.$ Moreover, "dense in $\mathbb R$" can be significantly strengthened (e.g. the points of non-differentiability can have cardinality continuum in every interval, and much more than even this). See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2747372/13130) for more details.

Comment: @Jamal: You might also keep in mind that to say there is *no* relation would mean that the concepts are logically independent of each other, which is not the case in this situation. But there *is* a relation: smoothness implies $\alpha$-Hölder continuity for all $\alpha$. The point is that the converse implication is false, as one shows using counterexamples.