# Can a function have a derivative where it has no value?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Consider the following function: $$f(x) = x^2 \mid x \in \mathbb{R}, \ x \ne 0$$

The derivative at $x=0$ seems to *want* to be zero, in the same way that $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0$

However, when I look at the definition of the derivative, this doesn't seem to work:
$$f'(x) =  \lim \limits_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f(x+\Delta x )-f(x)}{\Delta x}.$$ The function isn't defined at $f(x)$, so $f'(x)$ is also undefined. Would it make any sense to replace the $f(x)$ in the definition with $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0$? Then, I suppose we'd have $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} f'(x) = 0$?

Would it be permissible? Would there be any point?

Comment: I've arbitrarily defined it with a hole at $x=0$. Did I not represent that correctly?

Comment: What if I set f(0) = -1? Just to be pesky? The limit is still zero but it seems like the derivative is a mess.

Comment: If you set $f(0)=-1$, then the new function $f$ is not continuous at $x=0$, hence not differentiable at $x=0$. But take note of MPW's answer. If you extend the function $f$ by defining it at $x=0$, ir's no longer $f$, so you should use a new letter, so as not to cause confusion.

Comment: A naive approach might instead be to consider $$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x +h)-f(x-h)}{2h}.$$

Comment: @Shalop Your approach is not equivalent to the commonly accepted definition. Compare the results for the modulus function: $\mathbb R\ni x\mapsto|x|\in\mathbb R$. Your expression evaluates to $0$ while the original is _'undefined'_.

Comment: @CiaPan well that's why it's naive! Anyways, see the answer by md2perpe below. I guess that would be a more correct formulation of the quantity

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If a function $f$ is not defined at a point $x_0$ we can't evaluate the derivative at $x_0$ because in the definition of the derivative at $x_0$ we need $f(x_0)$.

However if $f$ is continuous in $0<|x-x_0|<r$ with $r>0$ and the limit $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=L$ exists we can extend $f$ to a continuous function in $|x-x_0|<r$ by letting $f(x_0):=L$.

Moreover if $f$ is also differentiable in $0<|x-x_0|<r$ and the limit $\lim_{x\to x_0}f'(x)=a$ then the **extended function** is also differentiable at $x_0$ and its derivative at $x_0$ is equal to $a$.

See also [Prove that $f'(a)=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f'(x)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257907/prove-that-fa-lim-x-rightarrow-afx)

Answer (score 11):

No.

You can certainly extend $f$ to a function $g$ as you indicate, but then you are really computing $g'(0)$, not $f'(0)$.

In that case, $f'$ agrees with $g'$ on their common domain, which excludes $x=0$.

Remember, if a function is differentiable at $x_0$, then it is continuous at $x_0$. In particular, it is *defined* at $x_0$.

Answer (score 10):

As has already been said, and as you have found yourself, the ordinary derivative is not defined. However, the symmetric derivative is defined in your case:
$$f'_{\text{symmetric}}(x_0) := \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0-h)}{2h}$$

A more general derivative is also defined (I'll call it *excluding*; I don't know if it has a name):
$$f'_{\text{excluding}}(x_0) := \lim_{h,k\to 0\\h,k \neq 0} \frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0+k)}{h-k} = \lim_{x_1,x_2\to x_0\\x_1,x_2 \neq x_0} \frac{f(x_1)-f(x_2)}{x_1-x_2}$$

Comment: *I don't know if it has a name* --- From my answer to [“Strong” derivative of a monotone function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85069/strong-derivative-of-a-monotone-function): "Besides *strong derivative*, three other names I’ve encountered in the literature are *unstraddled derivative* (Andrew M. Bruckner), *strict derivative* (Ludek Zajicek and several people who work in the area of higher and infinite dimensional convex analysis and nonlinear analysis), and *sharp derivative* (Brian S. Thomson and Vasile Ene)."

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to specify $h,k\neq 0$ in the limit subscript, is it? I would expect it to be implicit in the definition of a limit that the changing variable doesn't actually take on the value which it is approaching.

Comment: @DavidZ $\lim_{x_1,x_2 \rightarrow x_0}$ isn't quite standard notation. So it might be implying you get equal and defined results from $\lim_{x_1 \rightarrow x_0} \lim_{x_2 \rightarrow x_0}$ and $\lim_{x_2 \rightarrow x_0} \lim_{x_1 \rightarrow x_0}$, but that's not in general true. Or more likely it would mean $\lim_{(x_1, x_2) \rightarrow (x_0, x_0)}$, but this allows approach from any path on $\mathbb{R}^2$, including straight horizontal and vertical.

Comment: It seems to me that the defintion of $f'_{\text{symmetric}}$ says that if $f(x) = \lvert x\rvert,$ then $f'_{\text{symmetric}}(0)=0.$ But the definition of $f'_{\text{excluding}}$ then would say the derivative doesn't exist at $x=0,$ which seems a more sensible answer.

Comment: Thanks @aschepler for giving a good answer to why I wrote $h,k \neq 0$.

Comment: @DavidK. You are correct about the two derivatives of $|x|$. But wouldn't it also be reasonable to have $f'(x_0) = \frac12 ( \lim_{x \to x_0-} f'(x) + \lim_{x \to x_0+} f'(x) ),$ i.e. the mean value of the left and right limits of the derivative?

Answer (score 1):

You function does have a derivative, just not a "classical" or "strong" one. Instead your function has what's called a "weak derivative", which is technically not a single function but rather a class of functions for technical reasons from measure theory about zero-measure sets, but this class usually (in practical problems) has a single continuous or piecewise continuous representative. In your case, the function $g(x) = 2x$ is the continuous representative of the class of weak derivatives of your function $f$, namely because for any "test function" $\phi$ (i.e. a smooth and compactly supported function) on $\mathbb{R}$ we see that the relation of integration by parts holds:

$$\int_\mathbb{R} f(x) * \phi'(x) dx = \int_\mathbb{R} x^2 * \phi'(x) dx = - \int_\mathbb{R} 2x * \phi(x) dx = \int_\mathbb{R} g(x) * \phi(x) dx$$