# Does there exist such a monotone function?

Tags: real-analysis

Can we find a monotone function $f$ in $R^1$ satisfying that there is no continuous function $g$ equal to $f$ almost everywhere in every open interval $I$?

We know that a monotone function is differentiable almost everywhere,so I think the property of $f$ can not be too bad.but I don't know if $f$ can be approached by a continuous function for every open interval.I tried to construct some functions but didn't work...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "a monotone function is derivative almost everywhere", but the Cantor function is continuous everywhere but nowhere continuous.

Comment: @Bermudes I think the OP means differentiable. See beginning of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85069/strong-derivative-of-a-monotone-function?rq=1).

Comment: @Bermudes thank you,but can these two condition hold at the same time?It seems like a contradiction...continuous and nowhere continuous...

Comment: @Dog_69 Yes.Thank you.I am not familiar with those words yet..sorry

Comment: @Maxwell I think he was wrong too. According to [Wiki's page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function#Properties) the Cantor function is continuous (uniformly continuous) but it is not completely continuous.

Comment: Does a monotone increasing function which is discontinuous at all rational points do the job? The only possible discontinuities are jump discontinuities. I haven’t written a formal argument, though.

Comment: @LinearOperator32 Thank you.I think you are right.I will have a try.