# Pointwise limit of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convergence-divergence

Given a compact Hausdorff (I do not assume metrisability) space $K$ and a sequence $(f_n)_n$ of continuous real-valued functions on $K$ such that the pointwise limit of this sequence exists. Must the limit be Borel-measurable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

More generally, if $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of a set $X$, and $(f_n)_n$ is a pointwise convergent sequence of real-valued $\Sigma$-measurable functions on $X$, then $\lim_n f_n$ is $\Sigma$-measurable.  (The usual way to prove this is to consider $\liminf$ and $\limsup$.)  Since continuous functions are Borel-measurable, the answer to your question is yes.

It is worth mentioning that in the case where $K$ is an interval in $\mathbb R$, what you get is a [Baire class 1 function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_function), a very special type of Borel function.  A [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15088/is-every-lebesgue-measurable-function-on-mathbbr-the-pointwise-limit-of-con) asked whether every Lebesgue measurable function is a pointwise limit of continuous functions.

Comment: More is true: Because $K$ is compact Hausdorff, it is in particular locally compact Hausdorff, so it's a Baire space. Hence the limit of the $f_n$ must be continuous on a comeagre set of points in $K$ by the Baire-Osgood theorem.

Comment: [Proof of Baire-Osgood](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Baire-Osgood_Theorem).