# Are the continuous functions pointwise dense in the bounded measurable functions

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Suppose we have a compact set $K$. I know that the space $C(K,\mathbb{C})$ of continuous functions is complete with respect to the norm $\|f\| = \sup_{x\in K} |f(x)|$. Let $L^{\infty}$ be the space of bounded measurable functions (with the Borel subsets as $\sigma$-algebra). Is $C(K,\mathbb{C})$ pointwise dense in $L^{\infty}$ ?

Now, if this is true and suppose that $K$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$. I know from the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem that the polynomials on $K$ are uniformly dense in $C(K,\mathbb{C})$, so certainly pointwise dense. Are the polynomials on $K$ also dense in $C(K,\mathbb{C})$ ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See also [this related thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/15088)

Comment: What do you mean by *pointwise-dense*? $C(K)$ is not dense in $L^\infty$ because $C(K)$ is complete in the $\sup$-norm.

Comment: I mean that when you look at $C(K)$ and $L^{\infty}$ as subspaces of $K^{\mathbb{C}}$ with the product topology, does the closure of $C(K)$ contain $L^{\infty}$ ?

Comment: On the other hand, given a measureable function $f$ there is a sequence $f_n\in C(K)$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=f(x)$ for almost all $x$. But I am sure this is not what you mean.

Comment: No, that is exactly what I mean (although I just need essentially bounded measurable functions). Maybe I forgot to mention, but with $L^\infty$ I mean the essentially bounded functions modulo the ones which are essentially $0$ everywhere.

Comment: So, I understand that the question is whether the functions of Baire class $\le 1$ are dense in $L^{\infty}$ (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_function). I think this is true, because the characteristic function of any closed set $E$ is of Baire class $\le 1$; it is the pointwise limit of $(1-n\mathrm{dist}\,(x,E))^+$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Re: "I know from the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem that the polynomials on $K$ are uniformly dense in $C(K,\mathbb C)$". -- This is not true in general;  $K=\{z:|z|=1\}$ is a counterexample. See [Mergelyan's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mergelyan's_theorem).