# Equality of finite signed measures by showing that the integrals of every bounded continuous function coincide

Tags: measure-theory, signed-measures

In order to show the uniqueness of the Fourier coefficients of a signed measure, I need to show that :

> For any two finite signed measures $\nu_1, \nu_2$ on $\left([-\pi, \pi], \mathcal{B}_{[-\pi, \pi]}\right)$ such that : $\int f\mathrm d\nu_1=\int f\mathrm d\nu_2$ holds for every $f$ continuous (and bounded), we have:  $\nu_1=\nu_2$.

This property holds for finite positive measures ([Approximation of bounded measurable functions with continuous functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176379/approximation-of-bounded-measurable-functions-with-continuous-functions)) because the equality of integrals for a continuous function implies that of integrals of a measurable bounded function.
The answers in this thread are based on the fact that for $\mu, \mu'$ probability measures, $\mathcal{C}=\{B\in\mathcal{B}_{[-\pi, \pi]} : \mu(B)=\mu'(B)\}$ is a $\pi$-system. 
 Does this even hold here ?

EDIT: It does when $\nu_1([-\pi, \pi])=\nu_2([-\pi, \pi])$, (required to show that $\{B∈\mathcal{B}_{[−π,π]}:ν_1(B)=ν_2(B)\}$ is a Dynkin system), which is true in my case, since $\hat{ν_1}=\hat{ν_2}$.

Comment: Do you know the [Riesz–Markov–Kakutani representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem), stating that $\mathcal M(X)\simeq C(X)^*$?

Comment: Nope, that seems out of my reach for now. Plus the material I'm following didn't even feel the need to highlight the equality, so I thought it was going to be similar to the positive case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that both signed measures are finite, since otherwise we cannot expect that the integral over arbitrary continuous functions exists. You can approximate any interval $[a,b]$ by (for example) the sequence
$$g_n(x) := \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if } x \in [a,b] \\ nx + (1-na) &\text{ if } x \in [a-1/n,a] \\ -nx +(1+nb) & \text{ if } x \in [b,b+1/n] \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}  \end{cases}.$$
By the dominated convergence theorem (for signed measures) we get
$$\nu_1([a,b]) =\nu_2([a,b]).$$
Thus, both measures are equal on a $\cap$-stable generator of the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra. Now, you need to extend the uniqueness theorem for $\sigma$-finite measures. In fact, the same proof applies. Note that $$\mathcal{C}=\{B\in\mathcal{B}_{[-\pi, \pi]} : \nu_1(B)=\nu_2(B)\}$$ is a $\pi$-system containing a $\cap$-stable generator with a sequence $E_n \in \mathcal{C}$ such that $E_n \uparrow \Omega$.

For completeness, we should give reasons for the application of the dominated convergence theorem: By Jordan's decomposition theorem, you can write for a signed measure $\mu = \mu_1 - \mu_2$ with measures $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$. (Moreover, there exists a 'minimal decomposition' - called the Jordan decompisition.)

Comment: Of course the measures involved here are finite, I edited that, sorry.
The only problem remaining is that I can't prove that $\mathcal{C}$ is stable under intersection.  
I managed to do it when the measures are of probability, but since they don't have the same total mass, I couldn't do it

Comment: In the uniqueness theorem for $\sigma$-finite measures you need that there exists a sequence $(E_n)$  in $\mathcal{C}$ with $E_n \uparrow \Omega$. Of course, we need this here, too! And it is satisfied as we can take the constant function $f=1$ to get $\nu_1(\Omega) = \nu_2(\Omega)$.

Comment: By "uniqueness theorem for σ-finite measures" you mean the monotone class theorem right (although it doesn't require the existence of such a sequence)?  
Because that was the first approach I tried, but as I said, I couldn't prove that $\mathcal{C}$ is closed under intersections.

Comment: I mean [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Uniqueness_of_Measures) theorem. I called it 'uniqueness theorem for $\sigma$-finite measures'.

Comment: This theorem still requires to show that $\mathcal{C}$ is closed under intersections though :/  
Can you help me with that please ?

Comment: No, the proof shows that $\mathcal{C}$ is a Dynkin system, containing a $\cap$-stable generator. You don't need to show that the whole set-system $\mathcal{C}$ is closed unter intersections. (We need to use that  a Dynkin system with generator closed under intersection is a $\sigma$-Algebra. The proof can be found in the mentioned link.)

Comment: Oh I get you !  So, $\mathcal{G}=\{ [a;b] : -\pi\leq a<b\leq \pi\}\cup \{ \varnothing \}$ is our $\cap$-stable generator, and $E_n = [a-1/n, b-1/n]$ for example ?

Comment: Yes, you can also take $E_n  = [-\pi,\pi]$, because we are in a finite setting. (Both measures are finite. Taking $f=1$, we also see that $\nu_1(\Omega) = \nu_2(\Omega)$ as already mentioned above.)