# Proof of Lusin theorem

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> **Theorem (Lusin):** Let $f$ measurable and finite valued on $E$ a set of finite measure. For all $\varepsilon>0$ there is a closed set $F_\varepsilon\subset E$ s.t. $f|_{F_{\varepsilon}}$ is continuous and $m(E\backslash F_\varepsilon)\leq \varepsilon$.

The proof goes like:

Let $(f_n)_n$ a sequence of step function s.t. $f_n\longrightarrow f$. For all $n$, there is $E_n\subset E$ s.t. $f_n$ is continuous outside of $E_n$ with $m(E_n)<\frac{1}{2^n}$.

**my questions**

**1)** If $f_n$ is a step function don't we have that the set of discontinuity is nulle and thus $m(E_n)=0$ ?

**2)** When we say that $f_n$ is continuous outside of $E_n$, does it mean that $f_n$ is continuous on each point of $E\backslash E_n$ or does it mean that $f_n|_{E\backslash E_n}$ is continuous ? (of course, the first assertion condition implies the second one).

No problem for the rest of the proof.

Comment: What is a "step function" here? A simple function [linear combination of finitely many characteristic functions of measurable sets]?

Comment: My definition of step function is $f=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\chi_{R_i}$ where $R_i$ are rectangles. A simple function is not a step function. @DanielFischer

Comment: For question $2$, I'm pretty sure we mean $f_{n}|_{E - E_{n}}$ is what is continuous.

Comment: Okay, then the convergence $f_n \to f$ can [in general] only be a.e., not pointwise on the whole space, methinks. Not that it matters much.

Comment: Regarding point 1), it may have been forgotten to mention that $E_n$ should be open. While the set of discontinuities of a step sunction is indeed a null set, we need an open set containing it, and that cannot be a null set [except in the trivial cases].

Comment: It's not specified (Book : real analysis, Stein), but your remark make sense.

Comment: I asked a similar question a couple of years ago.  I actually ended up answering my own question, which I think will be helpful for you.  Here's a link to the question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/863636/questions-about-proof-of-lusins-theorem

Comment: Why does there exist the sets $E_n$ where $f$ is continuous outside of them? 
What if f is continuous on all of E? 
Also, how can you find these sets? Why don't we need a theorem or lemma to find these sets where f is discontinuous on the complement?