# Properties of Lebesgue measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be Lebesgue measurable. How to prove that for every $0<\epsilon<1$ there is $\delta>0$ and $A\subset [0,1]$ with $m(A)>1-\epsilon$ such that
$$|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon, \forall x,y\in A \text{ with } |x-y|<\delta?$$

($m$ denotes Lebesgue measure)

Comment: This is Lusin's theorem, which has been discussed at length on this site.

Comment: e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/863636/questions-about-proof-of-lusins-theorem

Comment: (This follows since a continuous function on a compact metric space is uniformly continuous.)