# Is there a counter example when $\delta=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am reading the following theorem: If $f$ is almost everywhere finite and measurable function, then for $\delta>0$, there exists a closed subset $F\subseteq E$ such that $\mu(E\setminus F)<\delta$ and $f(x)$ is continuous on F.

Does this theorem hold when $\delta=0$ too?

Comment: No. Let $C\subseteq[0,1]$ be a [fat Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) and pick $f=\mathbf{1}_C$ as the indicator function of $C$. Then we can prove that $f$ is discontinuous on any $F\subseteq[0,1]$ with $\operatorname{Leb}([0,1]\setminus F)=0$.

Comment: @SangchulLee That should be an answer ...

Comment: See Remark 1 in my answer to [Is every Lebesgue measurable function on $\mathbb{R}$ the pointwise limit of continuous functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/61284/13130). Of course, this is just a less less detailed version of what @Sangchul Lee said, but there may be other things in that answer also of interest.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is negative. Here is a counter-example:

Choose $E = [-7, 7]$ and let $C \subseteq [0, 1]$ be a fat Cantor set. This $C$ is a closed and nowhere-dense set which has positive Lebesgue measure. Then we choose $f = \mathbf{1}_C$, which is the indicator function of $C$.

Now let $F \subseteq E$ be any measurable subset such that $Z := E\setminus F$ has zero Lebesgue measure. Then $C\cap F$ has positive Lebesgue measure, and in particular, it is non-empty. Moreover, for each point $x \in C\cap F$ and for each open neighborhood $U \subset E$ of $x$, the intersection

$$U \cap (F \setminus C) = (U \setminus C) \setminus Z$$

is non-empty. This is because $U \setminus C$ is a non-empty open set of $E$, which itself follows from the fact that $C$ is closed and nowhere-dense. This implies that $f$ takes both values $0$ and $1$ on $U$, and since $U$ was arbitrary, we conclude that $f$ is not continuous at $x$. Therefore $f$ cannot be continuous.