# A question on Lusin's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $E$ be a bounded Borel set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and let $\mu$ be the $n-$dimensional measure of Lebesgue. Suppose that every relatively open set in $E$ has measure 0. Is it possible that $\mu(E)>0$?

Because if this is the case, we can take a measurable function  $f$  on a neighborhood of $E$, and , then by Lusin's theorem there is a closed set $F$ on which $f$ is continuous and $\mu(E\setminus F)=0$ by hypothesis on $E$.

Comment: Likely to be of use: [Is every Lebesgue measurable function on $\mathbb{R}$ the pointwise limit of continuous functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/61284/13130)

Comment: Thanks. I totally reformulated my question. Hopefully it is more clear.